# Como está interação funciona dentro de uma lista?

Tags: python-3.x

Após pesquisar sobre como criar listas com tamanhos aleatórios para realizar alguns exercícios encontrei a seguinte linha de código que satisfez minha duvida mas que criou outra

x = [i + 1 for i in range (random.randint(9, 15))]

Como a lista recebe apenas um loop como argumento? O que é está variável ''i'' que é iniciada antes do loop? e apenas lá pois mesmo quando dou o comando print , o erro de que ela não foi definida é lançado.